# How to install older ruby version on ubuntu Precise Pangolin?

Tags: ruby, versions, rvm

I got a present: older Rails tutorials that needs old ruby version. I try to install ruby-1.8 with the packet manager. I still got problems with the tutorial example code. Next I try rvm to install the old ruby version. Unfortunately I got an error. I do not know what to do. I search the internet. Many people got no problems with rvm.
rvm use

```bash
*ERROR: Branch origin/ruby_1_8_4 not found.*
```

and

```bash
*ERROR: Error running 'GEM_PATH="/usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.4-
  tv1_8_4:/usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.4-tv1_8_4@global:/usr/share/ruby-
  rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.4-tv1_8_4:/usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.4-tv1_8_4@global"     
  GEM_HOME="/usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.4-tv1_8_4" "/usr/share/ruby-
  rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.4-tv1_8_4/bin/ruby" "/usr/share/ruby-rvm/src/rubygems-
  1.3.7/setup.rb"', please read /usr/share/ruby-rvm/log/ruby-1.8.4-
  tv1_8_4/rubygems.install.log*
```

Please give me a hint.

Answer (score 2):

After the installation, try the following command ( if you have installed more than one Ruby edition ) and choose the appropriate version.

Or try the alternate ppa repository to install Ruby

```
$ add-apt-repository ppa:brightbox/ruby-ng-experimental
$ aptitude update
$ aptitude install <select-the-version-from-repository>
$ update-alternatives --config ruby
$ update-alternatives --config gem
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Mr. Oğuz Çelikdemir...I need a solution with rvm, because I got different rails tutorials with different ruby versions. I think the problem occurs because I installed ruby with synaptic. rvm should not know the existence of the ruby interpreters which I installed with the packet manager synaptic. I de-install rails and ruby and re-install it with rvm.

Comment: Dear friend, last two commands specifically designed for more than installation which you can select what version you want. The command will show you a list available Ruby versions with a number. When you enter a number, the system will recognize this version as a default! Just try and let me know the result.

Comment: Thanks for your concern. You are right. update-alternatives is indeed a solution. But I need rvm, because rvm allows you to set ruby versions for your system-wide and for singular projects within a configuration files.

Comment: Thanks for your concern...Your hints works for me. But I am still a little unhappy, because I want to set the ruby version in a project configuration file. RVM got this possibility with rvmrc, you can set ruby interpreters system-wide and project-only. I use scaffold to generate a rails project. Where should I put the update-alternatives lines to set the ruby versions only for a project. The command rvm list known shows me that ruby 1.8.4 is not among the known list, so you are right from the start. I spend 30 minutes with the rvm manual to see it.

Comment: try this link [Ubuntu 12.04 RVM Installation]{http://www.andrehonsberg.com/article/install-rvm-ubuntu-1204-linux-for-ruby-193}